# Finding the absolute maximum of the following 3d function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

$ f(x,y) = \frac{(\lambda_1x+\lambda_2y+\lambda_3)^2}{x^2+y^2+1} $

I know that the function looks like some deformed dorito chip depending on the lambda values. That is about as far as I've gotten.

I can't seem to solve this, given the unknowns and the fact that the positive numerator can change and create different limits for the overall function.

I'm probably going down the wrong path altogether and confusing myself more... could someone show me how to approach this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to blindly find the hessian and etc?

Comment: We haven't been exposed to this method yet. We mostly use Lagrange multipliers to approach these questions and basic techniques for solving partial derivatives.

Comment: I'm open to new approaches within the vicinity of what I currently know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us define $\mathbf{u} = [x,y,z]^T $ and $\lambda = [\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3]^T$. With this definition and ignoring that $z=1,$ you can formulate your problem as
$$ \max_{\mathbf{u}} \frac{\lvert \mathbf{u}^T \lambda  \rvert^2}{ \lVert \mathbf{u} \rVert^2}.$$

From this formulation it becomes clear that the solution has the form $\mathbf{u}^\star = c \lambda,$ where $c\neq 0$ is a scaling factor that does not change the value of our function. To obtain $z=1$ we can therefore choose $c=1/\lambda_3$.

Finally, we can conclude 
$$ x = \lambda_1/\lambda_3, y = \lambda_2/\lambda_3. $$

$Remark:$
The reformulated optimization problem is actually known as the Rayleigh quotient.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to take a partial derivative? The maximum, if there is one, must be at a point where both partials are zero.  That gives you two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: I know how to take the Partial Derivative. Are you talking about the Partials of the 2 functions (denominator, numerator)? Could you expand on that. It sounds like something I could comprehend.

Comment: No, you take $\frac {\partial }{\partial x} f(x,y)$ and set it to zero.  You then take $\frac {\partial }{\partial y} f(x,y)$ and set it to zero. The denominator of each fraction disappears, but the denominator in $f(x,y)$ shows up in the numerator of the partials.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the vectors $(λ_1,λ_2,λ_3)$ and $(x,y,1)$. This gives an upper bound and a condition for equality to that bound.